# exec for functions and stored procedures on squirrel-sql

Tags: postgresql-9.3, squirrel-sql

I am trying to run a function on Squirrel connected to PostgresDB. I am unable to execute functions or stored procedures. example: when i run

```
exec pglog_read('Thu');
```

I get the following error

```
Error: ERROR: syntax error at or near "exec"
  Position: 1
SQLState:  42601
ErrorCode: 0
```

Am i Missing anything.

I have checked for plugins and the following have been installed. [list of plugins on my squirrel client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yjakb.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As documented in chapter [Calling Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-calling-funcs.html) of the manual, use select:

```
select pgload_read('Thu');
```